# Poly1305 Key for MAC generation

Tags: chacha, poly1305

I just went through https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7539#section-2.6 (sections 2.5 and 2.6). There it is described how to generate one-time Poly1305 keys using the ChaCha20 block function (for this a 96-bit nonce is required).

I am asking myself how this is "better" or "more secure" in comparison to just use the key that is used for the ChaCha20 block function.

Comment: Better as in not reusing the same key for different purpose(s)?

Comment: @DannyNiu But if the key is always generated freshly during key establishment (e.g. using an HKDF with a random nonce/salt), then we dont need to extra use the KeyGen function ChaCha20, right?

Comment: That same ChaCha20 key would be used to encrypt the message, right? So it would be used for Poly1305 based authentication and encryption, hence dual purpose?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes no, I am only interested in the MAC generation using Poly1305 with a key that is always been freshly generated for each execution of the MAC function. The key is derived using an HKDF with a shared DH key and a random value for each execution (e.g. a nonce). I am asking myself whether it is possible (advisable) to use the output of the HKDF directly or to use it as an input for the ChaCha20 keygen to get a onetime poly1305 key First and use this as the Poly1305 MAC key.

Comment: Probably best to integrate above comment into the question; it is vital information required (be able to) to answer the question.

Comment: Do edit the question to reflect that information. A single ChaCha20 key can encrypt multiple message as long as each nonce is never used more than once. A single Poly1305 key can only validate one message. It breaks, even if the messages authenticated are unique. (This is in contrast to some other MAC functions, like HMAC. The same input will always produce the same HMAC output, but it would still be safe if messages include a sequence number. This is **not** the case for one-time MACs. They are still unsafe to use for more than one message, even if a sequence number is used.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote in the comments:

> no, I am only interested in the MAC generation using Poly1305 with a key that is always been **freshly generated for each execution** of the MAC function. The key is derived using an **HKDF with a shared DH key and a** random value for each execution (e.g. a **nonce**).

In the same RFC that you mention it is written (quoting Bernstein's paper):

> The original article ([Poly1305]) is titled "The Poly1305-AES
>      message-authentication code", and the MAC function there requires a
>      128-bit AES key, a 128-bit "additional key", and a 128-bit (non-
>      secret) nonce.  AES is used there for encrypting the nonce, so as to
>      get a unique (and secret) 128-bit string, but as the paper states,
>      "There is nothing special about AES here.  One can replace AES with
>      **an arbitrary keyed function** from an arbitrary set of nonces to
>      16-byte strings."

Now you've got HKDF, which is a keyed function, a nonce and an output which can be made 16 bytes. I say: go for it, but don't use the key for anything else, including ChaCha20 encryption or worse, calculating another authentication tag.

Just for reassurance: do please use SHA-256 or better for HKDF. Then it should be just as secure.

---

Do remember that you're now in unchartered territory. That means using libraries to implement this kind of functionality will be harder, compared - for instance - to just using the AAD of a ChaCha20/Poly1305 cipher to calculate a MAC.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! From your answer I understand that it is fine to use the output of the HKDF directly for the generation of the MAC (https://www.wolfssl.com/doxygen/group__Poly1305.html#ga9fe5cdf300868c2b14b9d4872d6cef3b). 

Is there any security improvement when using the output of the HKDF as in Input for the ChaCha20 KeyGen (https://www.wolfssl.com/doxygen/group__ChaCha.html ) and to use the output of the KeyGen as MAC Key? I am asking myself whether it does "worth" to have this intermediate step (which still should cost low ressources).

Comment: No, HKDF is designed to provide a perfectly valid key, I don't see how ChaCha would be able to improve the key material at all. Then again, with the same key and block size it should not decrease either.